# Python subprocess call sudo passwordless

Tags: subprocess, python-3.5, sudo

I am currently working in a remote environment which has a user with certain sudo permissions for which it does not require inputting any password.

Specifically it can perform some nginx commands without the need of a password, so far so good. The problem I face comes when I have a python script that takes care of checking for updates and if there are changes tries to reload nginx. As seen below

```
Popen(['sudo', 'nginx', '-T'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) 
call(["sudo", "systemctl", "reload", "nginx.service"])
```

When the script reaches one of this steps a prompt pops up on the terminal asking for a password, which should not be necessary since the user running the script has the permissions to run the commands without inputting it.

Question: Is there maybe a way, without hardcoding the password in a variable, to tell the script to "inherit" the permissions of the user when I run it?

Some additional information:

- If the script itself is invoked with sudo everything works, but sadly this is not an option and sudo should be used only for the specific parts that completely require it (nginx reloads)
- Python version is 3.5

EDIT: Solved this thanks to a friend:

The solution was to add the 'shell=True' paramater to the Popen.

```
Popen('sudo nginx -T'], shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be, that there is a mismatch in the sudoers nginx-path and the PATH variable used during script execution.

Try to either match the Popen call to the full PATH given in the sudoers file or adjust the PATH in the shell calling the Python script.

Comment: sadly this did not work but I found out the solution thanks to a friend, I will add it to the question